# Считать текст из файла

Tags: java, android

Ребята, у меня есть задание, но из-за неопытности не знаю как его выполнить.

На сервере есть файл какого-либо формата, к нему можно обратиться через ссылку (например: ex.com/test.txt). В данном файле написан текст. Моя задача считать этот текст.

Как мне это сделать?

С каким расширением должен быть файл, как в нем должна быть записана инфа, может на php или просто текстом, и как, самое главное, считать мне этот текст?

Файл будет txt к примеру,в нем будет следующее:

1) оповещения (текст)

2) google.com (ссылка)

Comment: Укажи ссылку на полный файл. Посмотрим, может парсингом каким удобнее всего это будет сделать.

Comment: @yapv добавил в вопрос

Comment: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/AsynchronousGet.java

Comment: @post_zeew как собственно пользоваться?Меня урл и что мы на выходе имеем?

Comment: @post_zeew краткий туториал напишите пожалуйста

Comment: @post_zeew русские символы не читает почему-то